# NullPointerException in jmsTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-jms

My `jmsTemplate` object is throwing a `NullPointerException` each time the send message is being called.

```
public class AlertServiceImpl implements AlertService{

@Autowired
JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

@Override
public void sendSmokeEventAlert(final SmokeEvent evt) {
    System.out.println(evt);
    System.out.println(jmsTemplate==null);
    jmsTemplate.
            send(new MessageCreator() {
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            return session.createObjectMessage(evt);
        }
    });
}
 }
```

My `applicationContext.xml` has all the necessary beans along with these ones that are part of the JMS service.

```
<!-- TESTING FOR JMS -->
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.spring.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
<property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
 </bean>
<bean id="queue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="jms.queue"/>
</bean>
<bean id="jmsTemplate"
      class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
<property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
<property name="defaultDestinationName" value="jms.queue"/>
</bean>
```

When I print `jmsTemplate==null` prints to true. I believe maybe its not wiring properly? Do I have to set up the queue in ActiveMQ?

Comment: how are you creating object of AlertService, is it through spring dependancy?

Comment: AlertService is through an interface I created with sendSmokeEventAlert(final SmokeEvent evt) as its method header.

Comment: Are you creating this like new AlertServiceImpl()? Please show the code where you are calling alertService.sendSmokeEventAlert and its configuration instead if it is not through annotation.

Comment: If you are creating the object AlertServiceImpl() by new Then it will not work, Please leave this upto spring to create object for you by defining <bean id="" class=""/> and use it

Comment: Its been a year and I'm still trying to get my head around Spring. Both you and sp00ms advice helped me out, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AlertServiceImpl` does not seem to be declared as a Spring bean anywhere. Add the `@Service` annotation on it (for example).

Comment: I've just instantiated it as an object and called the sendSmokeEventAlert(someSmokeEventObject) to it to be picked up by the queue.